# How to print the trained data size after retraining Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pre-trained-model

I am training my Keras model with 20k training set and then after few months I need to update my model(not training from scratch) only update my new incoming dataset to my existing model .

My question is, how can I ensure that my model is updated and not trained on new incoming  datasets?

```
#Training the model and validation_first_time on 20k training dataset
import time
t0=time.time()
history =model.fit(X_old,y_old,
          batch_size      = 64,
          epochs          = 150,
          validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
          shuffle         = True,
          verbose=2) #for visualization

print( "training time:", round(time.time()-t0, 3), "s")


#Training the model and validation_new for second time on 5k dataset
import time
t0=time.time()
history_new_data =model.fit(X_new,y_new,
          batch_size      = 64,
          epochs          = 150,
          validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
          shuffle         = True,
          verbose=2) #for visualization
print( "training time:", round(time.time()-t0, 3), "s")
```

No errors, but I need to ensure that my model is updated old+new datasets?
I have tried checking the size of the model 
and I have checked cross validation.
Is there any method to ensure this practically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are retraining your model on completely new data, then the model tries to fit into only the new data and may fail as it has lost the training on new_data.

Comment: Thanks @AshwinGeetD'Sa  ```model.fit``` is fitting to new data and  it forgets the old data being trained . But it will be useful if I get sample code for updating my model (old+new) datasets .

Comment: simplest approach will be to append the new data to old data, shuffle it and train the model again.

Comment: Thanks @AshwinGeetD'Sa . In my case I have 50k training set and the new data will be only appr 1k samples . Problem here is my frequency of incoming new_data will be high . So my model should be adaptive to new_data . So appending (old + new)data and training again wont be working out for this situation . I should try some other approaches like online learning or incremental learning .